# Form not loading in Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, messaging, private-messaging

The problem I'm having pertains to Simple Private Messaging plugin for a Rails 3 project.

My website is a marketplace, like GumTree.com, where people post their needs, and other can respond by clicking on 'Contact' button and filling out a form, which then submits to the poster.

The problem I'm having is that the messaging form is not loading, when I go to /messages/new, I get this error:

```
undefined local variable or method `is_private_message' for #<Class:0x12cf23578>
```

Code is below - grateful for any feedback!

Thanks,

Faisal

---

**USER MODEL**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :posts  
has_one :profile
has_private_messages

attr_accessible :email

validates_presence_of :email
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message =>"Hmm, that email's already taken"
validates_format_of :email, :with => /^([^\s]+)((?:[-a-z0-9]\.)[a-z]{2,})$/i, :message => "Hi! Please use a valid email"

end
```

**MESSAGE MODEL**

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

is_private_message

attr_accessor :to        

end
```

**ROUTES.RB** (relevant part only)

```
get "messages/new"
```

**MESSAGES> NEW VIEW**

```
<% form_for @message, :url => user_messages_path(@user) do |f| %>
<p>
To:<br />
    <%= f.text_field :to %>
    <%= error_message_on @message, :to %>
</p>
<p>
Subject:<br />
<%= f.text_field :subject %>
<%= error_message_on @message, :subject %>
</p>
<p>
  Message<br />
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
        <%= error_message_on @message, :body %>
</p>
<p>
  <%= submit_tag "Send" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

**MESSAGES CONTROLLER**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

before_filter :set_user

def index
if params[:mailbox] == "sent"
  @messages = @user.sent_messages
else
  @messages = @user.received_messages
end
end

def show
@message = Message.read_message(params[:id], current_user)
end

def new
@message = Message.new

if params[:reply_to]
  @reply_to = @user.received_messages.find(params[:reply_to])
  unless @reply_to.nil?
    @message.to = @reply_to.sender.login
    @message.subject = "Re: #{@reply_to.subject}"
    @message.body = "\n\n*Original message*\n\n #{@reply_to.body}"
  end
end
end

def create
@message = Message.new(params[:message])
@message.sender = @user
@message.recipient = User.find_by_login(params[:message][:to])

if @message.save
  flash[:notice] = "Message sent"
  redirect_to user_messages_path(@user)
else
  render :action => :new
end
end

def delete_selected
if request.post?
  if params[:delete]
    params[:delete].each { |id|
      @message = Message.find(:first, :conditions => ["messages.id = ? AND (sender_id = ? OR recipient_id = ?)", id, @user, @user])
      @message.mark_deleted(@user) unless @message.nil?
    }
    flash[:notice] = "Messages deleted"
  end
  redirect_to :back
end
end

private
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
end 
end
```

Comment: The Table does not exist tells you what to do. Run `rake db:migrate` to migrate your DB and add the tables. Maybe the plugin genereated some migrations (if you are using MySQL or anything similar)

Comment: @23tux I tried rake db:migrate, nothing happens, still getting same bug.

Comment: can you recreate db? Means drop  then create and then migrate ? and c whether this fixes or not!

Comment: @23tux i don't have a migration for message...it may be because i created the message model and controller manually, not using scaffold generate..

Comment: but if you create a model, your migrations gets created automatically. Check the migrations folder if there are some pending migrations.

Comment: @23tux i have checked the db:migrate folder, i see migrations for other models but not this one, nothing pending either. whats the best way to generate this migration?

Comment: @23tux i reinstalled the plugin and fixed a few of the other errors, but still getting this one when i go to /messages/new: undefined local variable or method `is_private_message' for #<Class:0x12d172c70>

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages there is no `is_private_message` method. However there is a `has_private_messages` method that you have already put in your User model.

I think you need to just remove `is_private_message`

**EDIT**

Did you execute this command? `rails generate simple_private_messages:model User Message` or something like that.
According to the code of the gem (https://github.com/jongilbraith/simple-private-messages/blob/master/lib/generators/simple_private_messages/model/model_generator.rb) theorically, you should have a migration generated, so the `rake db:migrate` should not be empty.

Comment: I get this error message now  :undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class    --- (this refers to line 1 of the form partial, <%= form_for(@message) do |f| %>

Comment: please see updated problem description and code above - i reinstalled the plugin, but still have 1 persisting error.

Comment: I think you have not initialized Message object `@message = Message.new`

Comment: @Pravin Please see messages controller updated above. I do have @message=Message.new in the new method